# Display different Button/Button Background depending on SharedPreferences Value

Tags: java, android, xml, button, sharedpreferences

Basically i want a Button to change to another one depending on the int Value stored in sharedprefs.
I have stage select in my game, if the user got enough score in level, then he can start the next one and i want to change the Button depending on that.
I'm setting up my Button's with custom Background created in XML Selector file located in drawable folder.
After that how i can call it in Java? 
I tried a bit with if statement but cant find the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);

if (settings.getBoolean("nextLevel", true) {
    button.setText("Level_2");
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             // Perform action on click
         }
     });
}
else {
    //Everything should be the same.
}
```

Check also the developer docs concerning SharedPreferences in android: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref